# How do I check for floating vertices non connected edges?

Tags: geometry

I'm doing a very basic tutorial and trying to recreate a model which has basic geometry, figuring out the best way to use edge flow and to tie up any NGONs.
The model seemed to be behaving very odd as I was trying to make cuts to an NGON. I've only just realised I had vertices and the odd edge overlapping in the NGON from previous attempts at doing this.

I know it was just sloppy work, but is there a way of quickly checking your model for any floating vertices and/or edges?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It removes disconnected vertices and edges.

[image]